# How to do math operations with multiple digits in ASM

Tags: assembly, x86

This is my code for now, but it can only do 1 digit numbers. It's for class and i dont know how to make it do multiple digits. Im still a beginner at ASM programming and i wanted to ask for help on how to do multiple digits.

```
.model small
.stack 4096h
.data
msg1 db 'Choose an operation:$'
msg2 db 'a. Addition$'
msg3 db 'b. Subtraction$'
msg4 db 'c. Multiplication$'
msg5 db 'd. Division$'
msg6 db 'You choose Addition.$'
msg7 db 'You choose Subtraction.$'
msg8 db 'You choose Multiplication.$'
msg9 db 'You choose Division.$'
msg11 db 'First number:$'
msg12 db 'Second number:$'
msg13 db 'Operation:$'
msg14 db 'Answer:$'
msg15 db 'Enter two numbers then choose the operation.$'
op1 db ?
op2 db ?
res1 db ?
res2 db ?

.code
start:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

_start:
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg15
int 21h
call newline
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg11
int 21h
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov op1, al
call newline
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg12
int 21h
mov ah, 01h
int 21h
sub al,30h
mov op2, al
call newline
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg1
int 21h
call newline
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg2
int 21h
call newline
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg3
int 21h
call newline
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg4
int 21h
call newline
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg5
int 21h
call newline
mov ah, 09h
lea dx, msg13
int 21h
mov ah, 01h
nt 21h
cmp al, 'a'
je _add
cmp al, 'b'
je _sub
cmp al, 'c'
je _mul
cmp al, 'd'
je _div

_add:
call newline
lea dx, msg6
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
call newline
mov ax, 0
mov al, op1
add al, op2
cmp al,0ah
jge _twodig
mov res2,al
jmp _ans

_sub:
call newline
lea dx, msg7
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
call newline
mov ax, 0
mov al, op1
sub al, op2
mov res2,al
mov res1,ah
jmp _ans

_mul:
call newline
lea dx, msg8
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
call newline
mov ax,0
mov bx,0
mov al, op1
mov bl, op2
mul bx
mov res2,al
jmp _mans

_div:
call newline
lea dx, msg9
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
call newline
mov ax,0
mov bx,0
Mov dx,0
mov al, op1
mov bl, op2
div bx
mov res1, dl
mov res2, al
jmp _dans

_twodig:
sub al, 0ah
mov ah,01h
add ax, 3030h
mov bx, ax
lea dx, msg14
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
mov dl,bh
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
mov dl,bl
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
jmp _loop

_ans:
lea dx, msg14
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
mov al, res2
add al, 30h
mov dl,al
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
jmp _loop

_mans:
mov dx, 0 
mov bl,0ah
div bx
mov ah,dl
add ax, 3030h
mov bx,ax
cmp bl,30h
je _ans
lea dx, msg14
mov ah, 09h
mov dl,bl
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
mov dl,bh
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
jmp _loop

_dans:
lea dx, msg14
mov ah, 09h
int 21h
mov al, res2
mov ah, res1
add ax, 3030h
mov bx, ax
mov dl,bl
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
mov dl,'r'
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
mov dl,bh
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
jmp _loop

_loop:
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
newline proc
mov dl, 0ah
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
mov dl, 0d
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
ret
newline endp

end start
```

Comment: I don't understand why you have made this so complicated. Read a number from the console input, store it in a register, read another number from the console input, store it in a second register, and then `ADD` (or `SUB` or `MUL` or `DIV`) those registers. That will give you support for either 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit, or 64-bit values, depending on the size of the registers that you use. Perhaps the problem is that you're only reading in 1 character a time from the console input? Consider using buffered input or some other way for the user to indicate that they are finished typing.

Comment: @CodyGray Changing the code to use [buffered input](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a) may not be much of a challenge. But looking at his code, he doesn't seem to have a real `atoi` function, and is just doing `sub al,30h`.  The steps for turning the buffered string "1234" into a register may be non-obvious to a newbie. Horlic, does it help to think of "1234" as 4 + (3 * 10) + (2 * 100) + (1 * 1000)?  Yes, that would be a pain to write, but I don't believe you are going to find any tools in either asm or dos that will do this for you. Makes you really appreciate c's libs, eh?

Answer (score 1):

It may help if you realize how computers work with numbers.

Unlike humans, they can't tackle abstract entities in thoughts, and that's what numbers are. Computers need some physical representation, to act upon and process it.

But humans do similar thing, if I would want to tell you something about number 1234, I will write it like that "1234", four font glyphs on paper/screen. This is not any more the real number, but a base-10 formatted "mirror" of it, far from perfect. And how do you read it back and convert into 1234 value? You understand that each digit is different power of ten, and you know how to work with those.

For computers the same principle is used, but their native base is 2, the digits 0/1 can be easily encoded as current/no-current in electrical wires/cells, so such single 0/1 digit is called "bit". As single bit can store only two values, we tend to group them by 8 together, forming a byte. Now one byte (8 bits) can store 2<sup>8</sup> different values, which when interpreted as unsigned integer numbers will cover range `0..255`. 16 bits can cover values from `0` to `65535` (or different, when you interpret the values of 16 bits different, for example with the top most bit interpreted as sign value you can cover integer values from `-32768..+32767`).

Note, that the 16 bits don't have any information, what kind of value they store, and how it should be interpreted. They are simply group of sixteen 0/1 values, and how you interpret them (unsigned, signed, separate bit flags, or even low precision float, or just colour on screen or frequency of sound, ...), it's up to [your] code to interpret that value in some way.

8086 registers are 16 bit, so when you want to use native arithmetic instructions like `ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV`, you need to encode your values first into 8/16 bits.

On input from user you have usually separate ASCII characters.

So when user enters "number" `1234`, you will often receive for example 5 bytes of values: 49, 50, 51, 52, 13 (the last 13 is "enter" key). Now try to run in head the following algorithm:

```
bx = 0, si = address to first input
while ([si] != 13) {  // until enter is detected
  ax = 10
  mul bx    ; 32bit "dx:ax" = bx*10
  bh = 0, bl = [si++]
  bl -= '0' ; '0' = 48
  bx = bx + ax
}
```

After first loop bx will be 1 (49-48 + 0).
After second loop bx will be 12 (50-48 + 1*10).
After third loop bx will be 123 (51-48 + 12*10).
After fourth loop bx will be 1234 (52-48 + 123*10).
Then the while condition will detect enter, and skip the calculation, and in bx you have value 1234 binary encoded in 16 bits (i.e. the electricity is in cells: `0000 0100 1101 0010`).

So that's one of possibilities, how to convert from separate digit characters into native binary value.

Then to display result you will have the reverse transformation, splitting the native binary value into digits for particular power of ten, converting that into ASCII characters, and outputting them to screen/file/etc.

All of this is usually easily available in any high level programming language, but rarely in ASM (some beginner friendly platforms provide this as part of OS calls, but DOS isn't one of them).

That said, to create your own full+correct replacement for clib `printf` and `scanf` is project for few weeks, and I'm not talking even about efficiency. But as long as you need just some basic integer conversions for learning, and toying, it's doable in a day(s). Just realize what is what, and pay attention how various types of values are encoded inside computer into the bits (and how many of them). Then simple math formulas can be used to convert from one representation to other.

---

BTW, there are ways (formulas), how to do all the arithmetic even with separate digits (i.e. doing calculation with "strings"). This is even sometimes practical, some of "arbitrary precision" libraries use similar principle to calculate with values which don't fit into native 8/16/32/64/128 bit values. So the answer above should be more like "unlocker" to give you idea, what you have in hands, and that you can do any conversion/calculation you want, when you understand what is what, and how it works inside CPU. It's not like the only possible way, how to work with values.